# How to web scrape listing details using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to do a webscraping project using `beautifulsoup`. Below is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.morphmarket.com/us/c/reptiles/pythons/ball-pythons/1419690'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
snakes = soup.find("div", class_  = "container--N6XSR")
print(snakes)
```

I am able to extract the HTML; however, when I print "snakes", the result is always `None`, and I don't understand why. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: so I cannot find the div with the class: container--N6XSR on the page

Answer (score 0):

You could not find the element because the content is loaded from an API and rendered dynamically. If you do not want to use `selenium` that could handle it like a browser would do, you have to fetch the data with `requests` directly via API and get a well structured JSON:

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://www.morphmarket.com/api/v1/listings/1419690/').json()
```

There are a lot of information in the JSON, to get just these for purchase, simply use `data` like a `dict` and pick needed information:

```
data.get('purchase_details')
```

Result:

```
{'order_details': None,
 'blocking_details': {'buyer_user_is_blocked_by_seller': None,
  'seller_user_is_blocked_by_buyer': None,
  'buyer_store_is_blocked_by_seller': None,
  'seller_store_is_blocked_by_buyer': None},
 'shipping_type': 'free_shipping',
 'shipping_price': 0.0,
 'shipping_price_display': '$0',
 'purchase_preventing_reasons_list': ['Buyer should be authenticated'],
 'seller_name': 'davegreen',
 'inquiry_message': None,
 'title': 'Cinnamon Special Het Monsoon Male',
 'price': 2000.0,
 'price_display': '$2,000',
 'price_currency': '$'}
```

May also read how to inspect network activity: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network